# Sending emails in python via loop

Tags: python, database, email, for-loop

Is there a way to send emails to all the email addresses in the database via for loops? I'm not very sure on for loops and needs help.

I followed this [page](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm) for email sample. SQL statement would be `select email from table name`

```
import smtplib

SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = "sender@example.com"
TO = ["user@example.com"] 

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

# Prepare actual message
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements  This should explain for loops.  What part of this process do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Because there would be a lot of emails from database, and i wanted to send email to all of the addresses with the for loops. Like when i write the query 
`cur1 = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
cur1.execute("Select nextofkin.email from nextofkin, messageDetails where messageDetails.sender_number=LAST_INSERT_ID(messageDetails.sender_number)") 
con.commit() 
last= cur1.fetchall()
#print "%s" %last

for row in last:
 print "%s" %(row["email"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download and import the correct Database interface. (MySQL or SQL Server etc.)
Then do something like this:

```
    import smtplib
    import MySQLdb

    SERVER = "localhost"

    FROM = "sender@example.com"
    TO = ["user@example.com","another@user.com","many@users.com"] 

    #SQL data access part
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='$$', db='emaildatabase')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select email from tablename where email is not null')
    db.commit()
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for item in rows:
        TO.append(item)

    SUBJECT = "Hello!"

    TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

    # Send the mail

    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

Let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: Hi thank you. But what if i want to send to addresses retrieved from databases straight away?

Comment: I hope I understand you correctly, but I would then change this part:        TO = ["user@example.com","another@user.com","many@users.com"]   to this:          TO = []

Comment: Do you use SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL.
Yeah, but how do i link the item with database? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: I have edited my answer, it might require minor modifications to work.

Comment: Thanks, It came out error like this though.. ` TO= TO+item
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, needed the "TO.append(item)" instead of "TO = TO + item"

Comment: Sorry just saw the comment. It works just fine with the TO=TO+item though.. There is an error for TO.append(item). `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Thanks, yes. I forgot, when you use the TO=() with parentheses (tuple) then you would use TO = TO + item. With TO=[] square brackets (list) it would be TO.Append(item). I hope I am correct.